# appying dos2unix on all files under folder

Tags: shell, cygwin, windows-server-2012

I am trying to appply `dos2unix` on all files.

```
find $WORKSPACE/itrp-sr -type f -exec unix2dos.exe {} \;
```

but is resulting in an error

> 1 [main] find 3468 fork: child -1 - forked process 4524 died
>   unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11 find: cannot
>   fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

This may be due to insufficient memory?

Comment: That's odd.  Have you tried a rebase?  Helps me sometimes when I'm getting odd fork errors - http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/Rebaseall

Comment: I bet you have a far better chance of getting a valid answer on the mailing lists at www.cygwin.com